# ServiceNow Rest API (using PowerBI)

Tags: url, powerbi, servicenow, powerbi-datasource, servicenow-rest-api

I'm on a project in which I need to get data from a ServiceNow instance and treat all data with PowerBI. I'm able to retrieve a big amount of data (Snow collect a lot of data), but I still need a way to filter data correctly. I'm calling to this URL:

[image]

Besides, I want also to apply a filter to retrieve just some specific registries from the table **Requested Items**. For that, I use the **sysparm_query** parameter to filter the field "**cmdb_ci**" and more specifically it's "**name**", something like:

```
&sysparm_query=cmdb_ci=What I need to Filter
```

Apart from this, I have also tried:

```
&sysparm_query=cmdb_ci.value=What I need to Filter
&sysparm_query=cmdb_ci.display_value=What I need to Filter
&sysparm_query=cmdb_ci.sys_id=What I need to Filter
&sysparm_query=cmdb_ci.name=What I need to Filter
```

But still not found the solution... as all these does not respond the solution needed.

**Does someone know how I can manage this?**

Thanks!!

JLG

Answer (score 0):

There are two "Configuration item" fields in **sc_req_item**: **cmdb_ci** and **configuration_item**. Make sure that you are using the correct one. Either **cmdb_ci.name=***value* or **configuration_item.name=***value* should work, depending on which of the two fields you are using. **cmdb_ci.value** and **cmdb_ci.display_value** will not work as there are no fields on the record with these names. **cmdb_ci.sys_id** should work if you are supplying a **sys_id** (although it is redundant to type **.sys_id** for a reference field).

You should first verify your query through the ServiceNow UI before attempting to use it in an API call.

1. Type **sc_req_item.list** in the Filter navigator
2. On the filter list select "Show related fields"
3. Get your filter to work correctly
4. Right-click on the filter and select "Copy query"

The next step is to test it using the REST API Explorer.

Final step is to configure your client tool (PowerBI).